# Save an int count and retrieve it to other activity

Tags: java, android, button, sharedpreferences

I  am creating a game in which the user is given hints for every question, when the user presses the hints button, then the hint count has to reduce by 1, I am having lots of activities which will have same type of logic. how to edit data and get it where ever we want. Please help me out

Comment: first time click has to trigger the count and from then clicking the button should not trigger the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just keep count value in a static variable inside your `Application` class.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you define.-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".YourApplicatinClass"
    ...
```

Then define `YourApplicationApplication` class like.-

```
public class YourApplicationClass extends Application { 
    public static int cont = 0;
}
```

And access `cont` value whenever you need with

```
YourApplicationClass.cont
```

Comment: where shoul I define yourApplicationApplication

Comment: It should be a class within its own YourApplicationClass.java file. However, notice you can define static variables in any class you already have.

Comment: On first click of the button in activity1, has to decrease the cont by 1, and in the first click  of the button in activity2 has to decrease the cont by 1 and the final cont value should return -2. from the second click it should not trigger the cont value, is it possible to write a code for the above. Thanks for your response

Comment: Sure, whenever you want to decrease your cont, just do something like `YourApplicationClass.cont --` (equivalent to `YourApplicationClass.cont = YourApplicationClass.cont - 1`

Comment: How to display the cont value in activities in TEXTVIEW,

Comment: `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId); textView.setText(String.valueOf(YourApplicationClass.cont));`

Comment: I want the user to know how many hints that are left for him, so I want to show the cont value in every activity

Answer (score 1):

You should just save it in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
Have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values), that should give you the hint how to work with it.
You can write a static method to read an decrement the value saved in there

```
class Activity1{


    onClickListener(){
        GlobalSettings.getHits(context)
    }

}


class Activity2{

    onClickListener(){
        GlobalSettings.getHits(context)
    }

}



class GlobalSettings{
    private static String PREFS_NAME = "myprefs";
    private static String PREF_HITS = "hits";
    private static int START_VALUE = 10;

    public static int getHits(Context context){
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return settings.getInt(PREF_HITS, START_VALUE); 
    }

    public static void incrementHits(Context context){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME , 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putInt(PREF_HITS, getHits(context) + 1);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void decrementHits(Context context){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME , 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putInt(PREF_HITS, getHits(context) - 1);
        editor.commit();    
    }

}
```

Comment: I have used Shared Prefs but I am not able to retrieve the value in other activity and modify it

Comment: Of course you can edit and retrieve the values from all activities from the same app.

Comment: can you provide an example with two activities

Comment: cmon you can do this by yoursels! But here you go

Comment: where should  I declare the global settings class

Comment: please read some Java Books and get to know it! Make a own File! This is a board for people how have already knowledge, or tried to get it by reading and searching, but the questions u are asking are not ment to be asked here, we do not prvide ready code, we provide answers!

Comment: Thank you for your suggetions, i am glad that you have spent your valuable time for answering my questions... hope more cooperation from you A.S

Comment: I would put it in a ew File